# DRF -django rest framework APi multiple file upload through API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am trying to upload multi-images to a single post which currently I am being able to upload only single image and get the confirmation through API. How can I make this to multi upload ?

My **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UploadedImage(models.Model):
   img = models.ImageField('Uploaded Image', upload_to='images') # stores uploaded image
   dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
```

my **serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UploadedImage


class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = UploadedImage
    fields = ('pk', 'img', 'dt_created')
```

my **viewsets.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from imageUpload.serializers import UploadedImageSerializer
from imageUpload.models import UploadedImage


# Create your views here.

class UploadImageViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = UploadedImage.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UploadedImageSerializer
```

Comment: you can access uploaded files from `request.FILES` and the key of your body ['img'](remember to use multiform-data for files upload. From value of ['img'] you can loop through it to get the uploaded files

Comment: I am sorry I am new django rest framework .. can you please elaborate you answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class UploadedImage(models.Model):
   img = models.ImageField('Uploaded Image', upload_to='images') # stores uploaded image
   dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
my serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UploadedImage

class UploadImagesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # here we limit how maximum the image is
    img = serializers.ImageField()
    img1 = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    img2 = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        create = YourModel(img=validated_data.get("img"))
        create.save()
        if validated_data.get("img1"):
            create = YourModel(img=validated_data.get("img1"))
            create.save()
        ....
        return create

class UploadedImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
    model = UploadedImage
    fields = ('pk', 'img', 'dt_created')
```

my viewsets.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from imageUpload.serializers import UploadedImageSerializer, UploadImagesSerializer
from imageUpload.models import UploadedImage
from rest_framework import parsers

# Create your views here.

class UploadImageViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = UploadedImage.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UploadedImageSerializer
   parser_class = [parsers.JSONParser, parsers.MultiPartParser,]
    
   def create(self, request):
       serializer = UploadImagesSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(...)
       return Response(...)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the create function . Thanks

Comment: how can i add those to my DB

Comment: i have updated my answerd

Comment: sorry for making this hard for you but this is not working . I am getting "Object of type ellipsis is not JSON serializable" while trying to fetch through API

Comment: i have updated my answerd

Comment: It is not working